# getting variable value from inside a callback function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to pull a variable's value from a callback function.
What am I doing wrong here?

```
var storyList = [];
var storyTemp ={};

// get list of all stories
db.getAllStoriesSet(function(err, reply) {
    if (err) throw err;
    else {
        storyList = reply;
        console.log("storylist inner: " + storyList);
    };
});
console.log("storylist outer: " + storyList);
```

in the above code, I am expecting the inner and outer storylist values to be same.
however the outer storyList value still comes as a null list.

EDIT: to add to the question.
I have initialized a variable storyList outside the async function. i am then taking the reply from the async function and putting it in the variable storyList. I was hoping to cheat my way out of the async pit of slow and brutal death that I have apparently dug for myself.
shouldnt it have worked?

Answer (score 5):

If `getAllStoriesSet` is asynchronous, then the line following its call is called before the callback is executed. So `storyList` is just like it was before the call.

That's the reason why you provide a callback : you must put inside the callback the code which needs the value of `reply`.

Comment: it is an async function.
How can i get the value of stoyList without a callback?

This whole async programming is making my life hell. :/ do i need to add another callback? The way I am daisy-chaining my async functions and callbacks, I might as well do synchronous programming.